# Computation on sparse data using GPU

Tags: matlab, optimization, gpu, sparse-matrix

I'm computing a function *f*(**x**) = exp(-**x**) in Matlab, where ***x*** is a vector of scalars. The function is computed on GPU, e.g.

```
x_cpu = [4 5 11 1];
x = gpuArray(x_cpu);
f = exp(-x);
```

then the result would be:

*f* = exp(-[4, 5, 11, 1]) = [0.183, 0.0067, 1.6702e-005, 0.3679].

Note that *f*(**x**(3)) = *f*(11) = exp(-11) = 1.6702e-005 = 0.000016702, which is a pretty small value. So, I would like to avoid computing the function for all **x**(i) > 10 by simply setting *f*(**x**(i)) = 0.

I can probably use the sparse matrix representation for **x**. However, the Parallel Computing Toolbox does not support operations on sparse matrices on GPU.

How would you approach this?

Comment: I'd recommend two implementations, one with sparse matrices, and one with GPU computing. Do some profiling and choose which one works better for you.

Comment: Thank you. I tested it: the GPU implementation (on full matrices) is a bit faster than CPU implementation with sparse matrices. just wandering if I can optimize the code on the gpu somehow. The vector **x** is pretty sparse.

Comment: See my answer below. It might be what you want.

Comment: Curious, how big is `x_cpu` in your actual implementation?

Comment: The `x_cpu` can have from 100,000 to 1,000,000 elements. Also the function `f = exp(-x)` is called thousands of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the Parallel Computing Toolbox does not support sparse matrix operations on the GPU, Jacket does.  So one possible approach is to simply use the different tool.

Disclaimer is that I work on Jacket, but I really do think it would be beneficial to you on this since it supports the things you want to do and that PCT does not do, and for [reasons here](http://accelereyes.com/compare).

Answer (score 1):

**PLEASE NOTE: This approach is a workaround meant to address the statement in the question:**

> So, I would like to avoid computing the function for all x(i) > 10 by
>   simply setting f(x(i)) = 0.

**In no way is this a truly "sparse" numerical method. This is simply a means to *"avoid computing the function for all x(i) > 10"* on the GPU in MATLAB**

```
% original input vector
x_cpu = [4 5 10 1 13 8 9]; 

% logical indeces of x where exp(-x) is significant
ix = x_cpu <= 10;

% values of x where exp(-x) is significant ("sparse" x)
x_sp = x_cpu(ix);

% Load our "sparse" vector to GPU
x_gpu = gpuArray(x_sp);

% create a vector of zeros for function output on GPU
f_gpu = parallel.gpu.GPUArray.zeros(size(x_cpu)); 

% do the calculations only for the "sparse" matrix on the GPU
f_gpu(ix) = exp(-x_gpu);
```

For when you want to get your computations back in the workspace, use [gather](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/gather.html):

```
f_cpu = gather(f_gpu);         % GPU --> workspace
```

**NOTE: I have not tested this code**

You should combine some of these initializations (`x_sp` or `ix`, maybe) to conserve memory and speed up the process. Honestly, the initializations and the transfer of data between the workspace and the GPU might actually make this whole process slower than before. Nothing left to do but try it!

Comment: the exponential function is actually somewhat more complicated than just exp(-x), it is something like exp(-x^2/sigma). So there's a little bit more computation for each element than I gave in the example.

Comment: There is an error when computing line `f(ix) = exp(-x);` on gpu, which states *"Conversion to double from parallel.gpu.GPUArray is not
possible"*. However, line `f(ix) = exp(-x_sp);` executes just fine on CPU.

Comment: Ah, forgot about [gather](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/gather.html). Try my updated answer.

Comment: This version works but it may be too slow because of `gather` command. I prefer to keep the result on gpu for further processing. I'll test the performance.

Comment: That's fine, but the problem was that `f` was on the CPU, and `exp(-x_gpu)` was on the GPU. To go from the CPU to the GPU, you need to use `gather`. So by all means, don't use `gather` when I did in my example, but in order to get your data back in the workspace (on the CPU) you will need to eventually use `gather`.

Comment: The last three lines of your code can be replaced with: `f = gpuArray(zeros(size(x_cpu)));` and `f(ix) = exp(-x);`. Then the data will stay on GPU.

Comment: I'll change my answer, and then you should consider accepting it :-)

Comment: Why is this answer getting so many downvotes? If you downvote, please have the courtesy of explaining yourself.

Comment: While this is not a truly sparse solution to the problem, +1 for showing how to use logical indexing.